# laravel route segments in blade

Tags: routes, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm stuck on what should be a trivial task accessing the index of a route with segments. I have a route defined in web.php as

```
Route::resource('supergroups/{supergroup}/musclegroups', MusclegroupController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

It appears in the route list correctly as:

```
GET|HEAD        supergroups/{supergroup}/musclegroups musclegroups.index › MusclegroupController@index
```

I'm trying to add this route in a blade file as follows.

```
:href="route('supergroups.'.$supergroup->id.'.musclegroups', $supergroup)"
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
Route [supergroups.1.musclegroups] not defined.
```

Which seems really strange because it's shown that way in the route list.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Comment: That route seems to be named `musclegroups.index`

Comment: That helped. I changed my blade file to say {{ route('musclegroups.index', $supergroup) }}. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per brombeer's comment, laravel was expecting me to use shorthand with a parameter in the blade file. This worked.

```
:href="route('musclegroups.index', $supergroup)"
```

Comment: fyi, in Laravel `{{ route(xyz) }}` points to a **named route** with name = xyz, `{{ url(abc) }}` will point to the **url** "abc"